# CSS selection 1, 2, 3 then 7, 8, 9 then 13, 14, 15 and etc

Tags: css, css-selectors

I need to add styles to every three divs perpetually but am having trouble with selectors

I've tried to explicitly write selectors for every three divs but I don't think that's scalable

```
        &:nth-child(-n + 3) {
            background: #000;
        }
        &:nth-child(n + 4) {
            background: red;
        }
        &:nth-child(n + 7) {
            background: #000;
        }
        &:nth-child(n + 10) {
            background: red;
        }
```

No errors, it's just the code won't scale well.

Comment: Post the HTML that you need it applied to please. We need a [mcve]

Answer (score 1):

you can write it like this: 
`nth-child(kn)` 
where k is the modulo you want. in this case 3:

```css
.container div{
  background: yellow;
  height: 10px;
  margin: 5px;
}
.container div:nth-child(3n){
  background: orange;
  height: 30px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
</div>
```

Comment: `3n+1` will start at 1